# I want to type cast in openlaszlo?

Tags: openlaszlo

I want to type cast in openlaszlo if any one work on it then tell me. One big task is pending for that smaller issue. It immediate. when i compare 2 digit number it get only first digit.

Comment: Add a code example of the code you are running. Which runtime are you using?

Comment: if((eg) <= (maxvar) && (eg) >= (minvar) && (maxvar)!=(minvar))
when number in two digit it take first digit and we get wrong output. if (3<=11) it return true

Comment: Number(variable) it working

Comment: Yes, if you retrieved the values as type String you have to convert to Number before comparing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number(variable) it working if you want to compare two number more than one digit then you must use Number for type casting otherwise compiler treat that number as a one digit number and u might be get wrong output.